# Error While running DotNetNuke 9 on a server

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Hi I get the following error while running DotNetNuke 9 on a server on Windows server 2012 r2 with iis

Could not find file `D:\Inetpub\vhosts\accuratedatabases.in\*****\DotNetNuke.config`

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\Inetpub\vhosts\accuratedatabases.in\finance2.berozgaribhagao.com\DotNetNuke.config'.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\Inetpub\vhosts\accuratedatabases.in\finance2.berozgaribhagao.com\DotNetNuke.config'.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +11794191
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1326
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +65
   DotNetNuke.HttpModules.RequestFilter.RequestFilterSettings.GetSettings() in E:\Websites\Developing\DotNetNuke\DNN_Platform3\Dnn.Platform\DNN Platform\HttpModules\RequestFilter\Config\RequestFilterSettings.cs:78
   DotNetNuke.HttpModules.RequestFilter.RequestFilterModule.FilterRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Websites\Developing\DotNetNuke\DNN_Platform3\Dnn.Platform\DNN Platform\HttpModules\RequestFilter\RequestFilterModule.cs:86
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +141
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

I searched on internet but could not find any solution. I tried hosting on both shared and dedicated windows server but the probelm is the same.
For your info I have the DotNetNuke.HttpModules.dll in my bin directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the DotNetNuke_install package instead. I was previously opening it in Visual Studio 2015 and then trying to run locally. but now i deployed directly to iis and for edits i open as a website in visual studio